# Converting list of list to dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

I have the following list of list:

```
[[u'3', u'4'], [u'4', u'5'], [u'7', u'8'], [u'1', u'2'], [u'2', u'3'], [u'6', u'7'], [u'5', u'6']]
```

I want to obtain:

```
{3:'4', 4:'5', 7:'8', 1:'2', 2:'3', 6:'7', 5:'6'}
```

List could be long, so it needs to be more efficient as possible.

The first element of each "pair" `[[first, second], ...]` is unique, so we can make a dictionary from it.

I tried with the following, but I think it will be slow:

```
def getdict(l):
    result = {}
    for e in l:
        result[int(e[0])] = e[1]
    return result
```

Comment: `dict(list_of_list)` is close -- The only difference is that you won't have integer keys ... `dict((int(k), v) for k, v in list_of_list)`

Comment: What dictionary should be produced from the input `[['1', '2'], ['1', '3']]`?

Comment: @mgilson Yes I tried with the first one, and I could not obtain the ints ones.

Comment: @Kevin the output would be `{1:'2', 1:'3'}`

Comment: But that's not possible. Dictionaries have to have unique keys. Try `print({1:'2', 1:'3'})` and it will display `{1: '3'}`.

Comment: Sorry. The first element of each pair is not repeated, so it is not a problem.

Comment: There should be a duplicate for this.

Comment: @FacundoGFlores -- To the extent that it's reasonable, it's helpful if you tell us what you've tried in your questions -- or at least techniques that you've looked at.  if you had, then it would make it clear that you explicitly want integer keys and not string keys.    The more you can spell it out, the better answers you'll get :-)

Comment: @mgilson I will edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
>>> l = [[u'3', u'4'], [u'4', u'5'], [u'7', u'8'], [u'1', u'2'], [u'2', u'3'], [u'6', u'7'], [u'5', u'6']]
>>> {int(key): value for key, value in l}
{1: u'2', 2: u'3', 3: u'4', 4: u'5', 5: u'6', 6: u'7', 7: u'8'}
```

Note that you would "lose" duplicates like in the @Kevin's example:

```
>>> l = [['1', '2'], ['1', '3']]
>>> {int(key): value for key, value in l}
{1: '3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    my_dict[int(item[0])] = item[1]
```